# Query Cassandra table based on UDID without allowing filtering

Tags: cassandra, uuid, cql

For example, I have a table set up like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    age int
);
```

When I try to query this table to pick out 1 entry based on uuid, I get an error: `Bad Request: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING.`

How would I properly query this table to pick out an entry based on its UUID.

Comment: Can you post your SELECT query?  Based on your table, querying with a WHERE clause filtering on id should work just fine without ALLOW FILTERING.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake on my end with the query I had, it works when I query with the primary/partition key.